# Update gitg without apt-get? Will I break something?

Tags: apt

On Ubuntu 16.04, I installed gitg using apt-get. Running

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gitg
```

tells me that:

```
gitg is already the newest version (3.17.1-1).
```

However, https://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg shows the latest version to be 3.26.

The installation instructions are straightfoward enough.

Can I install 3.26 directly, bypassing `apt`, without breaking anything? Are there any consequences down the line in doing so?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that could happen is that there are missing dependencies for `v3.26`, other then that, remember to `apt-get remove gitg` before installing the higher version.

If something does go wrong, which I highly doubt will, you can always `reinstall` the previous version.

Comment: Predictably, installing 3.26 from the repo complained about several missing dependencies. (https://pastebin.com/niZB2WLS)

* I tried installing the missing GDK file with `sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk-3-dev` ([https://askubuntu.com/a/779067/609530](source)), but apt complained about several 404s, suggesting I update the package lists or use `--fix-missing`.
* I had run `apt-get update` today, and running apt-get with `--fix-missing` still complains about 404s. (https://pastebin.com/s81mRns3)

What's my next step? Thanks for your help.