# Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pkg-config

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

When running

`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` I get the following error -

```
Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
```

I've tried installing missing packages (`sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk-3-dev` ), as per [pkg-config not finding gtk+-3.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779065/pkg-config-not-finding-gtk-3-0), however when running

`dpkg -l libgtk* | grep -e '^i' | grep -e 'libgtk-*[0-9]'` I still get `zsh: no matches found: libgtk*` with the same error still happening.

I'm unable to download certain go packages due to this issue - does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: To make your last command work the way you expect in zsh, either quote `libgtk*` or use `setopt nonomatch`

Comment: Thanks, I now get `zsh: no matches found: libgtk*, zsh: no matches found: libgtk-*[0-9]`

Comment: You are searching for wrong files, I think. You should search by `dpkg -S gtk+-3.0.pc` and `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` . Also I have a question - why do you run 18.04.4 instead of 18.04.5? You are probably missing major system upgrades by doing so.

Comment: @TomYeoman that *sounds* like you **un**quoted `'libgtk-*[0-9]'` instead of **quoted** `'libgtk*'`

Comment: I'm running ubuntu on WSL2, i'll look into upgrading :). I'm wondering if this could be part of my problem, as it's headerless? Thanks for the command @N0rbert I now get `libgtk-3-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtk+-3.0.p` returned

Comment: I still however get the `Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found` error message when running `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`

Comment: So, after 18 hours, you really understood that mention of WSL maybe helpful. Great! In any way output of `pkg-config --list-all --debug` may help.

Answer (score 3):

Use [search for *gtk+-3.0.pc*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gtk%2B-3.0.pc) on https://packages.ubuntu.com and then execute

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

When all packages installed you can try to reinstall pkg-config, and then manually raise pkg-config trigger/hook by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pkg-config
sudo /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook update
```

and then retry with

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
```

Comment: Thanks. When running that I get `libgtk-3-dev is already the newest version (3.22.30-1ubuntu4).`, I had already run the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk-3-dev` as mentioned on the original post, so that would explain it?

Comment: This is how this should work. You are probably have changed environment by Anaconda or something similar and gigantic.

Comment: @TomYeoman if you have manually deleted the .pc file you may need to **re**install the package (`sudo apt install --reinstall libgtk-3-dev`)

Comment: Thanks I've tried re-installing, and also ran `dpkg -S gtk+-3.0.p` to confirm it exists, I get the output `libgtk-3-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gtk+-3.0.pc`. However running `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` still returns `Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found`

Could it be that i'm running ubuntu in WSL2, which is heade less, and there's some sort of GUI requirement?